# Add validation to custom adittional required checkout fields in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

I have these WooCommerce fields that get added to the checkout page if a product has a specific category, but now I have set the two 'required = true', but it doesn't work?

This is how I made the fields:

```
<?php


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'add_video_short_checkout_fields', 1000, 1 );
function add_video_short_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        if ( has_term( 'video-short', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $product_title = $product->get_name();
            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            $unique_id = $cart_item_key;

            $current_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+72 hours'));
            $hours_to_add = 24;

            // Add custom fields for the product
            echo '<div class="video-short-fields group_extra_info">';
            echo '<h3>' . esc_html( $product_title ) . '</h3>';
            echo '<div class="video-short-fields form-row-group">';

            woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_field_1_' . $unique_id, array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'class' => array( 'video_veld customfield_start form-row-wide' ),
                'label' => __( 'Video Title Short', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => __( 'Your title', 'woocommerce' ),
                'required' => true,
                ), $cart_item['my_custom_field_1'] );



            $hours_to_add += 24;
    
        }

?>
```

---

Edit:

Thanks to @LoicTheAztec I found the solution.

I only needed to change the function name:

```php
// Field validation for custom checkout required fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_required_checkout_fields_validation' );
function custom_required_checkout_fields_validation() {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        if( isset($_POST['custom_field_1_'.$item_key]) && empty($_POST['custom_field_1_'.$item_key]) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('"Video Title Short" is a required  field.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing different functions names.

The function is named `add_youtube_short_checkout_fields`, but the hook references `add_video_short_checkout_fields`.

```
<?php
    
    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'add_youtube_short_checkout_fields', 1000, 1 );
    function add_youtube_short_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
    
            if ( has_term( 'video-short', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
                $product_title = $product->get_name();
                $product_id = $product->get_id();
                $unique_id = $cart_item_key;
    
                $current_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+72 hours'));
                $hours_to_add = 24;
    
                // Add custom fields for the product
                echo '<div class="video-short-fields group_extra_info">';
                echo '<h3>' . esc_html( $product_title ) . '</h3>';
                echo '<div class="video-short-fields form-row-group">';
    
                woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_field_1_' . $unique_id, array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'class' => array( 'video_veld customfield_start form-row-wide' ),
                    'label' => __( 'Video Title Short', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Your title', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required' => true,
                    ), $cart_item['my_custom_field_1'] );
    
    
    
                $hours_to_add += 24;
        
            }
    
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Mistake with copying the field works but it is not required

Answer (score 0):

There are mistakes in your code, and your question is not very clear. For custom checkout required fields, you need to add a validation process.

Try the following revisited code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'add_video_short_checkout_fields', 20, 1 );
function add_video_short_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_name = $cart_item['data']->get_name();

        // Check that 'my_custom_field_1' is set as custom cart item data
        if( isset($cart_item['my_custom_field_1']) ) {
            continue; // Jump to next cart item
        }

        // Restrict to 'video-short' product category cart items
        if ( has_term( 'video-short', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $current_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+72 hours'));
            $hours_to_add = 24; // what is that for?

            // Add a form field for the current product
            echo '<div class="video-short-fields group_extra_info">
                <h3>' . esc_html( $product_name ) . '</h3>
                    <div class="video-short-fields form-row-group">';

            woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_field_1_' . $cart_item_key, array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'class' => array( 'video_veld customfield_start form-row-wide' ),
                'label' => __( 'Video Title Short', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => __( 'Your title', 'woocommerce' ),
                'required' => true,
            ), $cart_item['my_custom_field_1'] );

            $hours_to_add += 24;  // what is that for?

            echo '</div></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

The field validation for custom checkout required fields:

```php
// Field validation for custom checkout required fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_required_checkout_fields_validation' );
function custom_required_checkout_fields_validation() {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        if( isset($_POST['custom_field_1_'.$item_key]) && empty($_POST['custom_field_1_'.$item_key]) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('"Video Title Short" is a required  field.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LoicTheAztec I found the solution.

I only needed to chacnge the function name.

```
// Field validation for custom checkout required fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_required_checkout_fields_validation' );
function custom_required_checkout_fields_validation() {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        if( isset($_POST['custom_field_1_'.$item_key]) && empty($_POST['custom_field_1_'.$item_key]) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('"Video Title Short" is a required  field.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I changed it so it works so your code helped me on the right path but didn't completely work in my case. that why I made it as a new answer.